# account page development

Tags: account

I am trying to make a account page that user can edit their password and profile in the front-end without plugin. I can't find any good tutorial in google. 
Are there some good tutorial about this? and can you give me some advice? 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many articles already available which shows how to build profile and change password screens without using any plugin.

This can help you with the purpose:
https://wpcode.io/howto-create-front-end-profile-edit-page-wordpress/